# Initiating phone call using custom alexa skill or google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, alexa-skills-kit, google-assistant

I have a use case. When the user says "Hey Google(Alexa), connect to housekeeping" then I have to call a housekeeping service or other services. Can we call an IP Phones/EPBAX using Alexa or Google Assistant using voice?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot place calls from an Alexa custom skill at this time.

Comment: Thank you @LetMyPeopleCode. Do you know about google?

Comment: Nope. Sorry about that.

Comment: Then how does ask my buddy alexa skill does do it ?

Comment: It doesn't connect you to your buddy for a conversation. It has a third party service make the call and convey the message. There is no real time voice or video communication (i.e. a call) going on between you and the buddy.